# Remove the last part of a String in Java

Tags: java, string, split, substring, lastindexof

My Code:

```
String Y = "part1 part2 part3", X = "part1";

boolean foundMatch = false;
while(!foundMatch) {
    foundMatch = Y.equals(X);
    if(foundMatch) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        Y = useSplitToRemoveLastPart(Y);
        if(Y.equals("")) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Implementation of `useSplitToRemoveLastPart()`

```
private static String useSplitToRemoveLastPart(String y) {
    // What goes here?
    // It should chop the last part of the String...
}
```

Can anyone help ...

Comment: Would you mind to define what "the last part of the string" is?

Comment: Give a concrete example of a given input and a given output.

Answer (score 31):

If you want part3 to be removed and provided that all the words are separated by space

```
String str ="part1 part2 part3";

String result = str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

Comment: The instructions implicitly require the use of `split()` which this solution does not. Not going to downvote, because I find this method to be superior (for the real world) but it doesn't meet the requirements set forth by the name of the method.

Comment: It may not answer the OP, but this is the answer that I, and apparently 10 others, were looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use split:

```
private static String useSplitToRemoveLastPart(String str) {
    String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    String result = "";
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        result = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(" " + arr[arr.length-1]));
    }
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your whole code can be optimized to:

```
boolean foundmatch = y.startsWith(x);
y = foundmatch? x : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String removeLastSubstring(String target, String toRemove){
    int idx = target.lastIndexOf(toRemove);
    target = target.substring(0, idx) + target.substring(idx + toRemove.length());
    return target;
}
```

You only need to pass it your target and the LAST substring you want to remove, example:

```
String s = "123 #abc# 456";
s = removeLastSubstring(s, "#abc#");
```

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to do it using split*, then you can do:

```
String s[] = Y.split(" ");
String n = "";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 1; i++)
        n+= s[i];
return n;
```

Comment: I want to +1 for solving OPs problem with the given instruction, but I also want to -1 for encouraging the use of `string += otherString` in a loop.

Comment: :) maybe I live in another world, but how do you connect strings?

Comment: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); for(...) { sb.append(s[i]); } return sb.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

By the way, If the method you need to build is called `useSplitToRemoveLastPart(String t)`, then I'd suggest you to *use split to remove last part*.

Take a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).